How can I solve a complicated nonlinear equation?
I was tried the following equation using Solve function:
$$h \left(\frac{b m e^{c (r-m)}}{c}-\frac{b \left(m e^{c (r-m)}-r\right)}{c}\right)+k
   \left(\frac{b e^{c r}}{c}+b r\right)+\frac{b p e^{c r}}{c}+2 b r^2 (h-s)=0$$
Solve[e^(c*r)*p*b/c + k*(e^(c*r)*b/c + r*b) + (h - s)*(2*r^2*b) + 
   h*(e^(c*(r - m))*b*m/c - b*(e^(c*(r - m))*m - r)/c) == 0, r]

But Mathematica gives a warning message:

"Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>"

In here, $r$ is the only variable and $k,c,p,b,h,s,m$ are constants. I tried to solve this equation by replacing the constants with numerical values. Mathematica outputs the same message.
How can I solve this?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! The first thing wrong in your code is e. In Mathematica, you should write capital E when you mean the exponential constant. The second thing is: This is a very complicated equation, and you will likely not be able to get any meaningful analytic result. Therefore, you can solve it numerically with NSolve after giving numerical parameters, for example:

NSolve[(b E^(c r) p)/c + h ((b E^(c (-m + r)) m)/c - (b (E^(c (-m + r)) m - r))/c) + k ((b E^(c r))/c + b r) + 2 b r^2 (h - s) == 0 /. {k -> 1, c -> 3, p -> 2, h -> 6, s -> -1, m -> 3, b -> 5}, r] returns 16 solutions.

using NSolve function with numerical values giving warning message:  NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve. >>

Which version of Mathematica are you using? Have you tried the code I have posted in the comment?

yes i tried. and thanks for corrections. my version is Wolfram Mathematica 8.0
